# Get "git checkout tag" to produce the same output as "git pull" diff list

Tags: git, tags, diff, git-checkout

I was just wondering if there's some sort of tag or parameter that we can provide to a

```
git checkout tags/{tag_name}
```

call that would provide an output similar to a regular `git pull`. I'm just looking for a single command to do a diff of the current revision against the code provided in the new tag.

I'm sure I can create a bash script to do this in two steps, but I was wondering if there was a way already part of Git to do it.

If not, then would would be the advice to get that diff (before **or** after doing the checkout)?  If I cannot do this in one line with Git, then I **will** be writing my own script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that follows a `git pull` is actually a default output for `git merge`, since pull is really just a fetch, followed by a merge. Here's an example:

```
$ git pull origin master
From c:/Users/Keoki/Documents/GitHub/bare
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 hello.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt

$ git reset --hard head^
HEAD is now at 53c0907 Revert "Change `git diff` meta color to cyan (OS X)"

$ git merge origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 hello.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt
```

So you see from above, the output, known as a "diff stat", is actually a part of a normal mege in Git.

### Getting Diff Stat Output

**There are no options to get the diff stat output with** `git checkout`. **You can, however, get the same output using** `git diff --stat`.

To get the stat before switching from a branch, tag, or commit X to another branch, tag, or commit Y, simply use

```
git diff --stat X Y
```

You can do this before or after checking Y out, since the `git diff` in this case isn't diffing anything in your current working copy.

### Documentation

According to the [official git-merge(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), the configuration variable `merge.stat` controls

> Whether to print the diffstat between ORIG_HEAD and the merge result at the end of the merge. True by default.

#### See Also

- [Official git-diff(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)

Comment: One final follow-up question:  If I wanted to do a git diff --stat X Y, then I need to know the current branch or tag.  I know that git status shows us this, but it tells us plenty of other stuff too.  Is there a command to get the current branch or tag, and have that be the only response? Or am I left needing to parse out the response of the git status command?  Thanks again!

Comment: @swafo what version of Git are you using? `git --version`? Also, why do you need the current branch if you're going to do `git diff --stat X Y`? Also, do you not have your command line already set up to display the current branch?

Comment: I'm trying to create a command line tool to make a safer push to production.  We (almost always) use tags to release new code.  That means that we will have the current code at any tag name.  I eventually found what I was looking for though: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the current branch name, and `git name-rev --tags --name-only HEAD` to get the current tag.  So that way I can do a call like: `pushcode {tagname}` and have it auto-detect the current branch/tag and run the diff --stat on those two before actually doing the code update.